# how access firefox internal url by javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

how can access firefox internal url by javascript ?

can i access for example about:memory by javascript ?

if can not access by javascript , can i access it by another way ?

Thanks .

Comment: Define "access."  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want open this url by ajax ! for example by jquery i try open it by this code : $.get('about:config', function(data){alert(data);});

Comment: Then what have you tried and how is it not working?  I'm going to take a wild guess that you won't be able to do this with JavaScript for a few reasons: 1) Browsers tend to limit JavaScript access to their internals for obvious security reasons. 2) Any AJAX code is likely to refuse to connect to anything but the server hosting the page because of the same origin policy. 3) These are browser-specific things, JavaScript itself doesn't really have useful knowledge of them.

Comment: i try in another way , i test this : window.location = 'about:config'; , but every url that start with about: not exec in javascript ! can access it by another way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chrome://global/content/aboutMemory.xhtml
```

But I'm not sure if [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will allow you to access that file via AJAX.

Comment: Same Origin Policy not allow to access it ! but i try to access to chrome://global/content/aboutMemory.xhtml by iframe , but not exec !

Answer (score 0):

Internal web-pages are accessed with URLs with their own protocol - `about:`. Trying to do XHR request from context of location with any other protocol (on the web that'd most often be `http:` or `https:`) will fail, because page you're trying to request and your context is not of [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

I've quoted relevant portion of page below and added emphasis:

> The term "origin" is defined using the domain name, **application
>   layer protocol**, and (in most browsers) port number of the HTML
>   document running the script. Two resources are considered to be of the
>   same origin if and only if **all these values are exactly the same**.

Comment: thanks , but not way to access this urls by any programming language ?